# Tycho Artifactory local repo; dependency to org.eclipse.jet unsolved?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I am creating some OSGI modules contains many plugin and features that require dependencies from p2 repo...

- I use tycho with artifactory
- In order to satisfy those dependencies , I add Kepler repo , ( tycho can't resolve dependencies from local repo) ...

my main pom.xml :

```
<repository>
<layout>p2</layout>
<id>kepler</id>
<url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler</url>
</repository>
```

And other artifactory local repo

```
<repository>
<id>central</id>
<url>{server.addr}/libs-release </url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>
.......
```

all seem ok, except this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from xx.xx.xx.xxx.xxx  to bundle org.eclipse.jet 1.1.1.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.] ???
```

How to find this dependency : org.eclipse.jet ??? Why tycho didn't find in Kepler p2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem...this is the solution , may be it will be useful for someone :

-First download org.eclipse.jet from  (http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/downloads/?project=jet).

-Deploy "org.eclipse.jet_1.1.1.v201101311015.jar" in Artifactory ( libs-release-local)

-Artifactory will generate code to include for dependency :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jet</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.jet</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

-Add this dependency declaration in module's pom.xml file where we need jet (not in main pom.xml)

-Build project (i use Jenkins for that).
-Success ...

Note that jet also need this dependency :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jet</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.jet.core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

There are may better solutions for that, but for now i' ll use this.Based on some forum JET has been overtaken by more recent tools such as Xtend or Acceleo ..
So Soon i ll switch to this new solutions ...

Answer (score 1):

`org.eclipse.jet` is not part of the Kepler p2 repository, as you can e.g. find out with this shell script:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
    -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler \
    -list | grep -F 'org.eclipse.jet'
```

If you can find a p2 repository with that bundle, you could also you reference that p2 repository by adding it to the pom.xml in the same way as the Kepler repository.

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/updates/ lists a few p2 repositories of the Modelling Project. Probably one of them also includes the bundle you want (and its dependencies).

Comment: thanks for your replay..

all sites in the link dosen't work... 

I got this error each time : 
    No repository found...

Comment: If the repositories listed on the web site don't work, you probably should [open a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Modeling) on the project.